# Constructing short exact sequences of Z-module

Tags: abstract-algebra

Recently I'm studying Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0,but now I get stuck with exercise 7.4 in chapter 3.

This exercise ask me to constrcut short exact sequences of $\Bbb{Z}-module$:

$0\to\Bbb{Z}^{\oplus{\Bbb{N}}}\to\Bbb{Z}^{\oplus{\Bbb{N}}}\to\Bbb{Z}\to0$

$0\to\Bbb{Z}^{\oplus{\Bbb{N}}}\to\Bbb{Z}^{\oplus{\Bbb{N}}}\to\Bbb{Z}^{\oplus{\Bbb{N}}}\to0$

I came up with the first，which likes the Hilbert's Hotel as the hint hinted.But I failed in applying this method to the second...

Sorry for my poor English..

Comment: Are those direct sums of $|\mathbb{N}|$ many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let the monomorphism map $(z_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ to $(z_1,0,z_2,0,z_3,0,\ldots)$ and let the epimorphism map $(z_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ to $(z_2,z_4,z_6,\ldots)$.

Comment: Thanks!  very clear to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Go the easy route and give a split sequence $0 \to A \to A \oplus C \to C \to 0$.  You can get away with this because $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality.  So, pick your favorite bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.  Do you see where to go next?

Comment: Thanks!  I got it.